# I render wrong the alert widget on yii2

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, yii2

I can´t properly render an alert on yii2 on the index page, im trying to render it on the funcion actionIndex so when i render the indez my query is written and my alert shows up but the alert renders before the index so it shows first the alert and then the index, how can i do it and how can i stablish a duration time to de pop up alert. Thank you this is de code:

```
 public function actionIndex()
    {
           $numero = Yii::$app->db
                ->createCommand("SELECT cantidad FROM productos WHERE 'nombre' = 'paco'")
                ->queryScalar();
         
         if (($numero) <50){
            echo  Alert::widget([
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'alert',
    ],
    'body' => 'Falta Stock en paco',
                ]);
      }  
         return $this->render('index');  
      
    }
```

Comment: Duration in your case wont solve the issue. I think that it is better to put `Alert` inside the `index` template. You are echo'ing alert modal before template is rendered, which is blocking the rest of the content to show up. Pass the result of the query to the template and then use JS or Yii2 `Alert` [widget](https://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/alert#usage) inside to echo alert or not. @Alvartex

Comment: should avoid embedding HTML or other presentational code - this is better done in views.  [link](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers#best-practices)

Answer (score 2):

Assalomu aleykum, in practice, alerts will be in view files, you should use the following pattern

Controller/method

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $numero = Yii::$app->db
        ->createCommand("SELECT cantidad FROM productos WHERE 'nombre' = 'paco'")
        ->queryScalar();

    $alertMessage = null;
    if (($numero) <50){
        $alertMessage = 'Falta Stock en paco';
    }
    return $this->render('index',['alertMessage' => $alertMessage]);
}
```

View file index.php

```
<?php
/**
* @var string|null $alertMessage
*/
?>
....
<?php if ($alertMessage): ?>
<?php echo  Alert::widget([
     'options' => [
       'class' => 'alert',
     ],
     'body' => $alertMessage
   ]);
?>
<?php endif; ?>
....
```